# Convert an object that is an array to an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

How do you (in C#) convert an object that is an array to an array of objects

Something in the following format:

```
bool Compare(object valueToCompare)
{
   if(valueToCompare.IsArray())
   {
      foreach(var value in (valueToCompare as Array)){
          if(Compare(value));
             return true;
          return Compare(value);
      }
   }
   else
       return Compare(valueToCompare);
}
```

**NOTE:** The code above doesn't do much. I'm just prototyping.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function?

Comment: You are only ever going to compare the first object in your array. Returning the result of `Compare` on the first value will ignore all other values in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the following are true:

- `valueToCompare` is an array *of reference types* (not, say, an `int[]` or `DateTime[]`)
- The array that `valueToCompare` is one dimensional (so either declared as a one-dimensional array or a jagged array)

You can cast directly to an `object[]` instead of `Array`.

```
bool Compare(object valueToCompare)
{
   Type t = valueToCompare.GetType();

   if(t.IsArray() && !t.GetElementType().IsValueType && t.GetRank() == 1)
   {
      foreach(var value in (valueToCompare as object[]))
          return Compare(value);
   }
   else
   {
       return Compare(valueToCompare);
   }
}
```

If your array is of value types, then you're basically out of luck.

If your array is multi-dimensional, then you'll just have to write similar checks to account for as many dimensions as you want to support.

**NOTE:** As you've written it, this function will just call itself recursively (the `else` branch calls itself with the same parameters) and eventually result in a `StackOverflowException`. I don't believe this is what you intended to do, but I have left it as-is since I don't know what you *actually* wanted to do.

Additionally this won't actually compile. I'm not sure what your loop is intended to compare; as it is, it will just compare with the first element of the array, but if the array is empty then it won't return a value (hence the compilation error).

What are you *trying* to do here?

Comment: Will the non-array branch result in a stack overflow?

Comment: @n8wrl: It sure will; I didn't even examine that portion of the code.

Comment: It WILL NOTE result in a stackoverflow

Comment: @Tawani: As it's written, it will. You might want to clarify your question, or at least post some example code that's a little closer to what you're actually doing.

Comment: Use valueToCompare.GetType().IsArray() instead of valueToCompare.IsArray()

Comment: @Tawani: That's another error in the example code, you're right; my intention here was to show you how to use the `object` as an array, as you'd asked. If this solves your issue, please be sure to accept this as the answer. If not, please edit your question to clarify what you need.

Comment: Note that only arrays where the element type is a reference type may be cast to object[]. An array of structs can (mostly) only be cast to an array of that kind of struct.  (I say "mostly" because the CLR does permit some unusual conversions, like int[] to uint[].)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks; I had forgotten about that caveat. I've updated the answer.